# ¿Como obtener la posición "x" y "y" de un elemento con respecto a otro que ha sido rotado?

Tags: javascript, html, css

buena noche, actualmente escribo un programa usando `javascript`, es un `drag and drop` de elementos `HTML`, el cual incluye la funcionalidad de rotar elementos usando el cursor. El objeto que permite realizar la rotación del elemento es otro elemento posicionado justo sobre el elemento a rotar, este cuenta con cuatro elementos circulares (uno en cada esquina) y un elemento circular central que representa el valor de `transform-origin`, todo esto funciona, sin embargo, al rotar un elemento, las propiedades `offsetWidth`, `offsetHeight`, `offsetLeft` y `offsetTop` cambian, esto se debe a la rotación ocurrida, entonces, para poder modificar el origen de la transformación usando el cursor debo encontrar la posición del elemento central (el que representa el valor de `transform-origin`) con respecto al elemento rotado.

```css
#center_element{
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 50px;
}

#rect_1{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="rect_1"></div>

<div id="center_element"></div>
```

El código de arriba es una representación del elemento que ha sido rotado y el elemento central.

[image: En esta imagen se muestran los valores a encontrar]

¿Como se calculan esos valores?

Espero puedan ayudarme y disculpen que no tenga un código "verificable" que poner aquí, es que no logro calcular correctamente esos valores.

Comment: ¿Quieres algo como `document.getElementById('center_element').getBoundingClientRect()`?

Comment: No, ese método no obtiene las posiciones con respecto al elemento rotado.

Comment: con getBoundingClientRect y un poco de geometría puedes obtener los vertices del rectangulo girado y luego el punto de x e y en el rectangulo respecto de una linea paralela al rectangulo que pasa por el circulo y de ahí la distancia de x e y.

Comment: Es es cierto, eso es lo que no logro resolver :(